# At the top or on the top

Tags: grammar, british-english, syntactic-analysis, descriptive-grammar

The society is growing at the top of the deep trenches left by centuries of colonial repression.

Can we write on top of the deep trenches here in the above question ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what "on top" or "at the top" of a *trench* means.  A trench has only a bottom and sides in my mind.

Comment: As @GeorgesPompidou hints, *growing something on / at the top of a trench* stretches the metaphor uncomfortably. The intent comes through quite clearly either way, though.

Answer (score 1):

For me it depends on the context and image you are trying to convey.

This might be a stretch, but if you intend to imply that the society has a weak foundation because of the repression (where the original culture has been destroyed or mixed with that of the colonial power and has lost value in some way) I would use "on top of". In that the current society has grown up and been built on top of a weak foundation. In this case the deep trenches provide a weak foundation to build upon if you imagine actually building a structure on top of them.

If you intend to imply something like the culture has grown and developed "up the sides of the trenches", and perhaps has or is starting to flourish, I would use "at the top". This is because someone could be "at the top" of his or her class in school for example or that someone can be "at the top" of his or her game.

I like johnblacksox's answer and discussion here: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/en-at-on-the-top-of.2019755/